# apply to a rolling window function loses column names

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a function that takes a `dataframe`:

```
def max_dd(df):
    print(df)

    return None
```

If I `print df.head()` before passing it to `max_dd`, it looks like this:

```
print(df.head())

            Close
Date
2010-08-10   7.95
2010-08-11   7.67
2010-08-12   7.72
2010-08-13   7.64
2010-08-16   7.59
```

However if I now pass `df` to `max_dd`,

```
new = df.rolling(45).apply(max_dd)
```

The function prints:

```
Date
2010-08-10    7.95
2010-08-11    7.67
2010-08-12    7.72
2010-08-13    7.64
2010-08-16    7.59
```

Why did it lose the `Close` column name and how do I get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Rolling.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html) func does not receive a DataFrame as parameter but a Series:

```
def max_dd(df):
    print(df)
    print(type(df))

    return None

new = df.rolling(45).apply(max_dd)
```

Output:

```
Date
2010-08-10    7.95
2010-08-11    7.67
2010-08-12    7.72
2010-08-13    7.64
2010-08-16    7.59
dtype: float64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>  # <- Not a DataFrame but a Series
```